# Javascript toggle; trying to make it so initial div is not displayes

Tags: javascript, html

Hello:  I am basically trying to have a toggle button (javascript) that when you click it a div appears and when you click it again the div disappears...

I found some code on here which basically does that; except the div is initially outputted on the page

(http://gerardsites.com/index)

I am new to learning javascript; and so I am trying to adapt this so that when page loads the div (gman123); is not shown; and then the button just toggles it...

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(btn, a) {
        var e = document.getElementById(a);
        if (!e) return true;
        if (e.style.display == "none") {
            e.style.display = "block";
            btn.value = "MENU";
        }
        else {
            e.style.display = "none";
            btn.value = "MENU";
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe(this,'gman123')" value="MENU"><br>

<div id="gman123">
    <br />
    How about this for test text?
</div>
```

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks so much,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleMe(btn, a) {
            var e = document.getElementById(a);
            if (!e) return true;
            if (e.style.display == "none") {
                e.style.display = "block";
                btn.value = "MENU";
            }
            else {
                e.style.display = "none";
                btn.value = "MENU";
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>    

    <input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe(this,'gman123')" value="MENU">
    <br>    
    <div id="gman123" style="display: none">
        <br />
        How about this for test text?
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS to hide the element initially...
Like so...

```
#gman123 {display:none}
```

Comment: i actually tried that before posting this and it worked; except you had to click twice to get the div to appear the first time; then it worked fine; so i was looking for another way; but tony's answer worked fine; thanks Charlie...

Answer (score 0):

your code is pretty fine. but since you wanna make this hidden on when the page load. so you have to hide it manually . Alternatively what you can do is call your function when page load is complete for that just add following code just before closing of your body Tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
toggleMe(this,'gman123');
</script>
```

This will hide it for just one  time . you can use this trick in future too.